# Linq: Group the results of several GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have the results of two GroupBy:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<long, MyClass>> result1 = ...;
IEnumerable<IGrouping<long, MyClass>> result2 = ...;
```

I want to put them together into one sequence. Some elements from result2 might have IGrouping keys that are also keys in result1. So the standard `Enumerable.Concat` does not work:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<long, MyClass>> result = result1.Concat(result2);
```

The items with the same key are mentioned twice in the result sequence. Apparently I need a special `Concat` for `IGrouping<TKey, TSource>` like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>> Concat<TSource, TKey>
    (this IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>> first,
          IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>> second)
```

I could ungroup all elements of the group and group them again, but that is of course a waste.

I've looked at the [source code of Enumerable.GroupBy](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,d60d1015ac88b667). That method creates a GroupedEnumerable object that will create a Lookup object as soone as the GroupedEnumerable is enumerated.

Should I do something similar, or is there a nicer (and easier to grasp) method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting the desired result is relatively easy by using `Concat` followed by `GroupBy` and flattening each resulting grouping with `SelectMany`.

The problem is how to turn it into `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` because there is no public standard class implementing that interface, it's returned by `GroupBy` and `ToLookup` implementations and also there is no `GroupBy` overload that allows what we need. So we need to make our own implementation, which fortunately is straightforward:

```
class Grouping<TKey, TElement> : IGrouping<TKey, TElement>
{
    IEnumerable<TElement> elements;
    public Grouping(TKey key, IEnumerable<TElement> elements)
    {
        this.Key = key;
        this.elements = elements;
    }
    public TKey Key { get; }
    public IEnumerator<TElement> GetEnumerator() => elements.GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}

public static class Grouping
{
    public static IGrouping<TKey, TElement> Create<TKey, TElement>(TKey key, IEnumerable<TElement> elements) =>
        new Grouping<TKey, TElement>(key, elements);
}
```

Now the implementation of the method in question could be like this:

```
return first.Concat(second)
    .GroupBy(g => g.Key, (key, gg) => Grouping.Create(key, gg.SelectMany(g => g)));
```

Comment: This method works. Even faster then the method I used (create a dictionary<TKey, List<TElement> and either add each not existing group, or addRange to existing group. Not sure though what the advantage of your static Create function is, instead of just using the constructor

Comment: Hi Harald, it's just for convenience, similar to `Tuple.Create`, in order to let compiler infer the generic arguments. Of course you can use directly the constructor if you wish.